# fastapi server hanged when forcefully shut down when runing websocket and redis

Tags: websocket, redis, python-asyncio, fastapi

hello guys I am learning fastapi and trying to create a chat with redis and chat app. so for that I have create a websocket endpoint

```
@app.websocket('/ws/{room_id}/{user_id}')
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket:WebSocket, room_id:str, user_id:str):
    await socket_manager._add_user_to_room(room_id, websocket)
    messager ={
        "user_id": user_id,
        "room_id": room_id,
        "message": f"User {user_id} connected to room - {room_id}"
    }
    await socket_manager._broadcast_to_room(room_id, json.dumps(messager))

    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            messager ={
                "user_id": user_id,
                "room_id": room_id,
                "message": data
            }
            await socket_manager._broadcast_to_room(room_id, json.dumps(messager))
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        await socket_manager._remove_user_from_room(room_id, websocket)
        message= {
            "user_id": user_id,
            "room_id": room_id,
            "message": f"User {user_id} disconnected from room - {room_id}"
        }
        await socket_manager._broadcast_to_room(room_id, json.dumps(message))
```

I have created a redis class to which initiate redis connection and have method for publising and subscribing.

```
class RedisPubSubManager:
def __init__(self, host='localhost', port=6379):
     
     self.redis_host = host
     self.redis_port = port
     self.pubsub = None

async def _get_redis_connection(self)->aioredis.Redis:
    return aioredis.Redis(
        host=self.redis_host, 
        port = self.redis_port,
        auto_close_connection_pool=False,
        
    )

async def connect(self):
    self.redis_connection = await self._get_redis_connection()
    self.pubsub = self.redis_connection.pubsub()

async def _publish(self, room_id:str, message:str) -> None:
    return await self.redis_connection.publish(room_id, message)

async def _subscribe(self, room_id:str)-> aioredis.Redis:
    await self.pubsub.subscribe(room_id) 
    return self.pubsub

async def _unsubscribe(self, room_id:str) -> None:
     await self.pubsub.unsubscribe(room_id)
```

and the websocket manager to handle websocket.

here is the websocket manager code.

```
class WebsocketManager:
def __init__(self):
    self.rooms = {}
    self.pubsub_client = RedisPubSubManager()

async def _add_user_to_room(self, room_id:str, websocket:WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    if room_id in self.rooms:
        self.rooms[room_id].append(websocket)
    else:
        self.rooms[room_id] = [websocket]
        await self.pubsub_client.connect()
        pub_subscriber = await self.pubsub_client._subscribe(room_id)
        asyncio.create_task(self._pub_sub_data_reader(pub_subscriber))


async def _broadcast_to_room(self, room_id:str, message:str):
    await self.pubsub_client._publish(room_id, message)

async def _remove_user_from_room(self, room_id:str, websocket:WebSocket):
    self.rooms[room_id].remove(websocket)

    if len(self.rooms[room_id]) == 0:
        await self.pubsub_client._unsubscribe(room_id)
        del self.rooms[room_id]

async def _pub_sub_data_reader(self, pub_subscriber):
    try:
        while True:
                msg = await pub_subscriber.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
                if msg is not None:
                    room_id = msg['channel'].decode('utf-8') 
                    all_socket = self.rooms[room_id]
                    for socket in all_socket:
                        data = msg['data'].decode('utf-8')
                        await socket.send_text(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await pub_subscriber.close()
        return
```

and everything seems fine, but after some chat when I try to shut the server with CTRL + C command it get hanged while closing the websocket connection succssfully. I dont know what I am doing anything wrong here. I am not even error in terminal. the server get stuck with this message in terminal.

```
    INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 51047) - "WebSocket /ws/loveme/nehat78692" [accepted]
INFO:     connection open
^CINFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     connection closed
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [4259]
```